# Error: 'set' object has no attribute.. - Python3

Tags: class, python-3.x, dictionary, pandas

I'm working on a program that needs to take rows I have in a table from pandas and store each one as a dictionary entry with one column as the key and the others stored in an object with that key. It seems to work ok and I get no errors when it's looping to add them to the dictionary, but if I try to call a specific item from that dictionary using syntax like SeqDict['key'].classattribute, I'm getting an error saying "'set' object has no attribute 'classattribute'.  Am I using the wrong syntax or is there something else wrong with my code?  This is the first time I have ever tried programming so sorry if I have made a stupid mistake or my code is written very inefficiently.

The first half of my code seems to work fine

```
import os
import pandas as pd

print("Please move your CSV to the desktop before continuing.")
csvfilename = input("Enter the name of your CSV file: ")
desktopfilepath = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/")
csvfilepath = desktopfilepath + csvfilename

seqtable = (pd.read_csv(csvfilepath, 
                    dtype=str, 
                    header=0, 
                    usecols=["Well", "Core Sample ID", "Sample ID", "Exon"]))

newseqtable = pd.DataFrame.dropna(seqtable)
print(newseqtable)

y = len(newseqtable.index)
print(y, "files to rename.")
```

I'm assuming this part is where I'm doing something wrong

```
class SeqID:
    def __init__(self,well,sequence,exon):
        self.well = well
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.exon = exon
SeqDict = {}

x = 0
for x in range(y):
    ID = newseqtable.iat[x,1]
    well = newseqtable.iat[x,0]
    sequence = newseqtable.iat[x,2]
    exon = newseqtable.iat[x,3]
#    print(ID + "," + well + "," + sequence + "," + exon + ".") #This works fine when I choose to run it
    SeqDict[ID] = {SeqID(well,sequence,exon)}
SeqDict  #This prints the dictionary keys I would expect

SeqDict['key'].well  # This returns the error when I insert a key
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

> ```
> SeqDict[ID] = {SeqID(well,sequence,exon)}
> ```

creates a 1-set. You probably meant:

```
SeqDict[ID] = SeqID(well,sequence,exon)
```

Comment: That fixed my problem.  Thanks so much. :)